# python functions for beginners

Tags: python, function

I'm somewhat new to python - I at least thought I had a solid understanding of the syntax but can't seem to figure out why this function does not work.

I want to write a function to capitalize the letters of a string.

```
string = 'Bryan'

def caps(word):
    word.upper()

caps(string)
```

What am I not understanding here?  Seems basic to me but can't figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *need* to specify a `return` explicitly.

replace

```
word.upper()
```

with

```
return word.upper()
```

If no return statement is specified, `None` is returned by default, Hence the result.

```
string = 'Bryan'

def caps(word):
    return word.upper()

returning_value = caps(string) #Note that you need to catch the returning the value. 
print returning_value
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do two things:

1. Because [`str.upper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) returns an uppercase *copy* of the string on which the method was called, you need to return `word.upper()` from function `caps` and then
2. Reassign the variable `string` to that return value.

Here is how your script should look:

```
string = 'Bryan'

def caps(word):
    return word.upper()

string = caps(string)

print string  # Print the new uppercased string
```

Demo:

```
>>> string = 'Bryan'
>>> def caps(word):
...     return word.upper()
...
>>> string = caps(string)
>>> print string
BRYAN
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = 'Bryan'

def caps(word):
    word.upper()

caps(string)
```

I think you are missing a print command.

```
def caps(word):
        print word.upper()
```

If you want value back in a variable then you will have to return the value in function and assign it to a variable.

```
def caps(word):
        return word.upper()

string = caps(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember to ask yourself, what do I want this function to do? 
In many cases, you might want it to give you the result. eg return

```
string = 'Bryan'

def caps(word):
    return word.upper()

newstring = caps(string)
print newstring
```

In some cases you may just want the function to do what you were going to do anyway.

```
string = 'Bryan'

def pcaps(word):
    print word.upper()

pcaps(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also work too. You can assign the word.upper() to a variable and still call it word.

```
def caps(word):

 word = word.upper()

 return word
```